# Implementing MessagePack using Javascript

Tags: javascript, msgpack, messagepack

I recently read about using the MessagePack in WEBAPI to improve the performance.

Though I am not able to consume the same in client side using javascript.

I read in one of the forum to use the https://github.com/msgpack/msgpack-node

But I am really confuse on how to use the same.

It would be great, if someone can post an working example including the JS files that would be required.

Thanks